# How to know what language is "default" for the utilities?

Tags: batch-file, command-line

I'm creating a tool in batch to check disk drives for errors and fix them using `CHKDSK` command !

This command works only on french machine : `echo O | CHKDSK !fix! /f` and dosen't work on english machine ?

This command works only on english machine : `echo Y | CHKDSK !fix! /f` and dosen't work on french machine ?

This what i did so far  :

```
@echo off
Title Check Disk drives for errors and fix them by Hackoo 2016
mode con cols=65 lines=5 & Color 0A
set TmpLog=TmpLog.txt
set Log=%computername%_%~n0.txt
If Exist %TmpLog% Del %TmpLog%
If exist %Log% Del %Log%
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /f "tokens=2" %%i in ('wmic logicaldisk where "drivetype=3" ^|find /i ":"') do (
    set "fix=%%i"
        Call :Affich !fix!
    (
        echo !fix! Drive 
        echo ************************
        echo(
        echo O | CHKDSK !fix! /f 
        echo(
        echo ************************
    )>> %TmpLog%
)
EndLocal
CMD /U /C Type %TmpLog% > %Log%
If Exist %TmpLog% Del %TmpLog%
echo(
cls
echo(
echo   Save your work - Reboot of your computer in two (2) minutes
echo(
echo   Enregistrer vos documents - Redemarrage du PC dans 2 minutes 
start "" %Log%
Shutdown.exe /r /t 120 /c "Enregistrer vos documents - Redemarrage du PC dans 2 minutes"
pause>nul
Exit /b

:Affich
Cls
echo(
echo               ***********************************
Echo                Please wait a while Scanning "%~1"
echo               ***********************************
Timeout /T 2 /nobreak>nul
```

So, i'm looking for a solution to let this script work on both french and english machines

Any ideas ?

Comment: Could you check the error message and execute the other command based on that?

Comment: What is the prompt text for both languages?

Comment: good .bat script, but isn't all you're really asking is how to know what language is "default" for the utilities? That must be in the registry someplace (I didn't find any `Language` like variables in my `set` output). Maybe recast this Q more narrowly to answer the defualt language Q, although Dennis's idea can be your last resort. Good luck.

Comment: What is the opposite selection option in French? if it is `N` like also for English, you could perhaps pipe `N` initially, capture the result by `for /F`, extract the parenthesised part like `(Y/N)` and get the applicable letter...

Comment: I'm thinking like @shellter how to know what language is "default" for the utilities? i will edit the title !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do both O and Y

```
(echo Y
echo O)|CHKDSK /f !fix!
```

Comment: This is a clever solution , Thank you ! TSnake41 ;)

Answer (score 2):

Since you are relying on wmic anyways you can use `wmic os get locale, oslanguage` to find out the host settings.

I believe you need implement a conitional check against the OSLanguage value.
Table of language codes: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb895996

As I am always confused with notions of locales and languages I also mentio
Locale codes can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964664.aspx